# Return promise value from observable subsciption

Tags: javascript, angular, async-await, observable, subscription

Is there any chance to return from helpMe function value from getDataFromApi() ? So far every time i call this function i get "null" value.

```
       async function helpMe() {
            let promise = null;
            let sub = someService.someObservable.subscribe(async () => {
               promise = await getDataFromApi()
            })
            subscriptions.push(sub)
            return promise;
        }
```

The first goal is i need to store subscription in global sub array. The second goal is when i get response with status 400 - I dont want to open modal. Only when i get 200 and everything is allright i want modal to be opened.

```
function async load() {
  const promise = await helpMe();
  openModal();
}
```

Comment: I might be blind here, but why do you need the observable here? Can't you just do `let promise = await getDataFromApi()`

Comment: Besides, as far as I remember, `await` does not work over a `subscribe` result, since it returns an Observable which can't be "awaited". You should rather convert the observable to a `Promise` if you want to `await` it (hence promise being null)

Comment: How often does `subscribe` trigger the callback? If multiple times, it makes no sense to use promises anyway.

Comment: What is `subscriptions`?

Comment: I need to store this subscription in global subscriptions array for futher actions in other service.

Comment: you are pushing the promise into your subscriptions though, not the sub, in the line before the return.

Comment: You are right, fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Passing an `async` function to `subscribe` is pointless - it throws away the returned promise, it doesn't wait for anything. You would need to use

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    someService.someObservable.subscribe(resolve, reject);
})
```

or just call the builtin [`toPromise` method](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/Observable#topromise-):

```
async function helpMe() {
    await someService.someObservable.toPromise();
    return getDataFromApi();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using async/await feature, you could just go with plain `rxjs`. The `switchmap` operator might help you here:

```
public helpMe()
{
  return this.someService.someObservable.pipe(
    switchMap(result =>
    {
      return someDataFromApi();
    }),
    tap(resultFromApi => {
      // ... do something with `resultFromApi` from `someDataFromApi`.
    }),
  ).toPromise();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We will use Promise to return the subscribed Observabal value in the following way

```
const getUser = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return UserInfoService().subscribe({
        err: err => reject(err),
        next: res => resolve(UpdateUserInfo(res)),
    })
})
```